# AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'current_user_saved_tracks'

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotipy

Using Spotipy and am attempting to 'current_user_recently_played'

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope = scope, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth = token)

saved = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
print(saved)
recent = sp.current_user_recently_played()
print(recent)
```

sp.current_user_saved_tracks() runs just fine, sp.current_user_recently_played() apparently doesn't exist even though it is clearly in the documentation https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#more-examples.

Running - v2.4.4 - January 4, 2017

Thanks ahead of time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Google Drive\Python\Spotify\try_req.py", line 19, in <module>
recent = sp.current_user_recently_played()
AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'current_user_recently_played'
```

Comment: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_recently_played

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version?

Comment: As far as I can tell v2.4.4 - January 4, 2017, is the most recent version. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: @KlausD.Thanks for the reminder, added above. Although I don't think it adds much

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to get the code manually. [The installation via pip is outdated.](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/211)

Navigate to where you installed Spotipy (for me it was `C:\Users\[myName]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\spotipy`), open `client.py` and replace the code with the newer code found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plamere/spotipy/master/spotipy/client.py).

Comment: you can use `pip show spotipy` and reference the "Location" path to find where the package is installed

Comment: this answer should be marked as correct. this fixed it for me, finally. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the outdated version on PyPi, as *Mangohero1* already pointed out. The following method is probably easier than manually changing code.

You can install the latest code like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/plamere/spotipy.git --upgrade
```

([source](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/211#issuecomment-369863112))